# UK (and EU) Ban on Credit Card Charges, does that cover Business to Business (b2b)?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, payment

The UK Government are bringing in a ban on credit card surcharges on 13th of Jan 2018 (based on a EU directive), but I can't find any information whether this includes b2b or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find more info in this PDF:
https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/664065/payment-surcharges-guidance.pdf

> Limitation of surcharges: business to business
>   payments under Regulation 6A(2) and consumer
>   to business payments under Regulations 4 and
>   6A(2)

in summary you can still charge credit card surcharges as long as its the same as the (average) actual charge the payment process charge.